# When do I use ほう with より?

Tags: grammar, particle-より

Take this sentence, for example:
"日本語がドイツ語より面白いです"
Up until now I've never seen より without ほう (still quite a beginner), so I'm wandering if "日本語のほうがドイツ語より面白いです" is different in any way (maybe it explains it as a choice between German and Japanese)?

Next:
"車で行くほうがバスで行くより安い"
Could I somehow say this without ほう? Or do I always use ほう? It is confusing because "俺は旅行するよりうちにいたい" does not use ほう after the verb.

As you can see, I'm a little confused as to when I do/do not use ほう, and would appreciate your help.

Comment: If I find 日本語がドイツ語より面白い in Lang-8, I'd correct it into 日本語のほうがドイツ語より面白い unless it's an answer to "what language is more interesting than German" instead of "which is...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「日本語がドイツ語より面白いです」and「日本語のほうがドイツ語より面白いです」 is the same meaning, but in this second instance I would say that you are slightly emphasizing the fact that "Japanese is more interesting".

You certainly could say this 「車で行く方{ほう}がバスで行くより安い」without the 「方{ほう}」.

「安いのはバスより車。」"It is cheaper to go by car than bus."

As for your other example,

「俺は旅行するよりうちにいたい。」"

You could word it like this.

「俺は旅行するよりも家{うち}に居た方{ほう}がいい。」"I would rather be at home than go on holiday."

I would say it is gets things across much more clearly when using 「方{ほう}」as it is easier to use it when comparing. But, as long as you are getting the meaning across, you could use it or leave it out as you please.